# Hide YouTube Video For Some Countries

Tags: files

Hello I Am Making A Website On Drupal And I Am Adding A YouTube Video On Some Page So I Want To Hide These Videos From Some Countries example I Want To In Usa So I Want to hide in india  So Which Module Or Way That I Can Do It

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try https://www.drupal.org/project/geo_block. It will allow you to add your video to a block and choose which countries should or should not see it.

Keep in mind however that this, like most other region blocking/detecting tools can be tricked.